# Condition such that domain homeomorphic to graph implies continuity

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that the domain of a continuous function is homeomorphic to the graph, but the converse is false. Is there any condition we can impose so that it is true?

Comment: What is a counterexample for the converse?

Comment: @freakish see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101003/a-simple-example-of-a-non-continuous-function-whose-graph-is-homeomorphic-to-the?rq=1

Comment: What spaces are we talking about here? Do you mean a function from $\Bbb R\supset D \to \Bbb R$, or do you mean a function from $X \to Y$ with graph a subspace in $X\times Y$?

Comment: @PedroGarcía yeah, these counterexamples take advantage of a disconnected domain, in fact with infinitely many components. I wonder whether such counterexample exists for a connected domain.